# How to convert underscores to hyphens?

Tags: uri

I am currently working with Drupal 6. I just want to know how to convert all the underscores in the URL of my website to hyphens.

Comment: I'm afraid without a lot more detail, this question is going to be closed as being far to vague or broad in scope.

Comment: Yes, more details would be good. I'm guessing you are talking about the separator in aliases created by pathauto. I wrote an answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. We are not a support forum or anything, trying to hurry us is pointless. No one is paying us to answer you. So please ask your question in a form you wouldn't mind to see in a professional knowledge library.

Answer (score 2):

At admin/build/path/pathauto change the separator from underscore to hyphen and make sure the other punctuation settings are the way you like (the ones that say "Replace by separator").

Then at admin/build/path/delete_bulk delete all the aliases that you want to change.

Then recreate them at admin/build/path/pathauto by checking "Bulk generate aliases for nodes that are not aliased" in Node paths, User paths etc. as needed.

Comment: Of course this will break most links in content's body. And it does not cover links created within modules, with `hook_menu` and `hook_menu_alter`.